Enterprise data model design for small business
I work at a small company that buys inventory and resells either the raw inventory or packages it up into bundles for resale. We have an in-house software and are redoing our data model for an analytics database that helps with decision-making for purchasing and sales.
Our company sells three theoretical items: (1) an orange, (2) an apple + banana bundle, (3) a banana + orange bundle. The important distinction is that the first item is a single unit of raw inventory, while the latter two are bundles of raw inventory.
We are deciding between two data models. In the first, we store raw inventory and bundles in the same table. This results in many NULL values for items we don’t sell, which makes data validation more challenging. In the second, we have separate tables for raw inventory (rawInventory) and products we sell (product). This results in repetition of some rows, primarily single piece products, i.e. orange, which appear in both the rawInventory and product tables.
The relationship between products and inventory is many-to-many and can be sufficiently modeled in either design.
What are the drawbacks to each of these schemas? Is the distinction between raw inventory and salable goods purely a business decision, or are there other considerations from a database design standpoint? How should we decide on a model?



. Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Making tables for subtypes is not DB normalization. How can you represent inheritance in a database?
How do you effectively model inheritance in a database? Strategy for “Which is better” questions How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? [ask] [Help]

You want 2 separate tables to have a more normalized design. see Database_normalization
Also with 2 tables a raw/bundle type field is not necessary. It is simply the count of rawinventory records per product. Count(pkRawInventory) > 1 means bundle.
2 tables also means you are not limited by how many items are in a bundle.

Making tables for subtypes is not DB normalization. PS That wiki article has a lot of misconceptions/errors, including, DKNF does not belong in that sequence of NFs.
